# Remove GraphCurve list on ZedGraph

Tags: c#, graph, zedgraph

I am new in C# and trying to create zedgraph of lessor sensor.
First I create a global variable and write code for graph. My graph is working but after reached to the point of 100 of x axis it will overlap to old line.  z1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear(); command is not working. I tried listPointsOne.clear(); command also but that clear the line and doesn't show anything on graph. Please help me out with this. 
My code is below :

```
        string DatafromCOM;
        double[] x = new double[100];
        double[] y = new double[100];
        int i;
        PointPairList listPointsOne = new PointPairList();
 private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                while (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    DatafromCOM = serialPort1.ReadLine();
                    double iData;
                    var ok = double.TryParse(txtKQ.Text, out iData);
                    if (DatafromCOM.Trim() != "" && ok)
                    {
                        i= (i + 1) % 100;
                        x[i] = i;
                        y[i] = iData;
                        listPointsOne.Add(i,iData);

                    }
                }

            }
            catch { }
        }
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                z1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();
                z1.GraphPane.AddCurve(null, listPointsOne, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);
                z1.AxisChange();
                z1.Invalidate();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clear the curvlist

```
string DatafromCOM;
        double[] x = new double[100];
        double[] y = new double[100];
        int i;
        PointPairList listPointsOne = new PointPairList();
 private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                while (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    DatafromCOM = serialPort1.ReadLine();
                    double iData;
                    var ok = double.TryParse(txtKQ.Text, out iData);
                    if (DatafromCOM.Trim() != "" && ok)
                    {
                        i= (i + 1) % 100;
                        x[i] = i;
                        y[i] = iData;
                        listPointsOne.Add(i,iData);

                    }
                    z1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear(); // Change here
                }

            }
            catch { }
        }



private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            z1.GraphPane.AddCurve(null, listPointsOne, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);
            z1.AxisChange();
            z1.Invalidate();
    }
```